# Clear FileUpload Content in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

How to clear the textbox content in a FileUpload control in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The ASP.NET `FileUpload` control maps to the HTML `input` element with `type="file"`. This element is considered Read-only and you cannot change it directly.

However, there seem to be atleast three workarounds to accomplish the goal of "clearing the field" :

a. Reset the form, either using script or by providing a `input type="reset"` button.

b. Re-establish the input field in the DOM by setting its attributes again:

```
var fu = document.getElementById("fileUpload");
if (fu != null)
{
  fu.setAttribute("type", "input");
  fu.setAttribute("type", "file");
}
```

c. Recreate the `innerHTML` of the field from the existing `innerHTML` as [demonstrated here](http://gusiev.com/2009/04/clear-upload-file-input-field/):

```
var fu = document.getElementById("fileUpload");
if (fu != null)
{
  // You may be able to use the cached object in `fu`, but I'm not sure.
  document.getElementById("fileUpload").innerHTML = fu.innerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Hi nice trick but for me following worked instead of innerhtml

```
            var fu = document.getElementById("flUpload");
            if (fu != null) {
                document.getElementById("flUpload").outerHTML = fu.outerHTML;
            }
```

regards,
Harish

Answer (score 5):

I have just Used the following in the Button click event in the code behind ...

```
protected void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    flUpload = new FileUpload();
}
```

The postback caused by the button click allows a page refresh and creates a new instance of the FileUpload control.

Answer (score 3):

These worked on FF, Chrome, IE7/8/9

```
//Method 1

var fu = $('#docUpload')[0];  
fu.value="";

var fu2= fu.cloneNode(false);
fu2.onchange= fu.onchange;
fu.parentNode.replaceChild(fu2,fu);
```

OR:
    //Method 2:

```
document.getElementById('docUpload').outerHTML =     
    document.getElementById('docUpload').outerHTML;
```

Answer (score 2):

Recently I needed the same thing and neither of the suggested workarounds worked for me (in more than one browser). The tests I made were done on IE8 and Mozilla 6.0. The thing that worked in IE didn't work in Mozilla and vice versa.

In IE:

```
var fu = document.getElementById("<%= fileUploadImage.ClientID %>");
if (fu != null) {    
    fu.setAttribute("type", "input");
    fu.setAttribute("type", "file");
}
```

In Mozilla:

```
var fu = document.getElementById("<%= fileUploadImage.ClientID %>");
if (fu != null) {        
    fu.outerHTML = fu.outerHTML;
}
```

I tried all the possible variations - always calling **getElementById**, calling it only the first time, calling it twice... I tried with **innerHTML**, too but there was never a solution that worked on both browsers.
That's why I came up with something like:

```
function clearFileUpload() {
    var fu = document.getElementById("<%= fileUploadImage.ClientID %>");
    if (fu != null) {
        try {
            fu.setAttribute("type", "input");
            fu.setAttribute("type", "file");
        }
        catch (ex) {
            fu.outerHTML = fu.outerHTML;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach that works for internet explorer and Firefox - in c# behind code:

```
File1Upload.ID = null;
```

Comment: this is simple method,but in my code have 3 file upload control i try with this ,but it clear all uploaded file instead of only one.

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub ClearAll()

    txtExample.Text=""
    txtInfo.Text=""

    fuPics.Dispose
    fuDocs.Dispose

End Sub
```

This sub works to clear the contents of the file upload control text field when the sub is called from a button such as `btnClear`. The above code works in asp.net visual web pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the FileUpload control with response redirect back to page itself and you can store the file in a session variable you can use on the next round trip.

```
protected void PageLoad(EventArgs e){



   if(FileUpLoadControlId.HasFile)
    {
        Session["data"]=FileUpLoadControlId.PostedFile.InputStream;

        Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, true);
     }

    else if( Session["data"]!=null)
    {

         //massage data here 

         //and post back
         Session["data"]=null;
         Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, true);

    }

 }
```

The response redirect reinitializes the view state

Answer (score -1):

How about just

If (File1Upload.HasFile) Then
           File1Upload = Nothing

Comment: Tha's fine if you want to remove the control!